# Site on mobile not shrinking

Tags: mobile, drupal, viewport

I have a Drupal site where the site on mobile isn't shrinking. It was working fine a few days ago and when I logged in today to do more work, it isn't anymore. I can't seem to figure out why.

I've tried several options for the viewport and none have made a difference. It may be that I've just looked at this code for too long and I'm just missing something.

It's just the front page: http://inv3nt.tgci.com/home

The inner pages are still under construction as far as the theme and such goes, so they're all messed up right now.

Eventually the site will get its own mobile theme, but for now I need this one to scale appropriately on mobile devices. Wish I could figure out what changed in the last few days to make it not work when it was previously.

Thanks for any help you can give. :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have no responsive theming, you have also set a min-width on the page wrapper meaning the page can not go smaller than 1200px

```
#wrapper {
  min-width: 1200px;
}
#main-content {
  width: 1200px;
}
```

You will need to add some media queries http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp
eg.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  #wrapper {
    min-width: 100%;
  }
  #main-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

You will also need to fix other issues such as the header and where you have 2 or four column elements.

You should look at creating a mobile first theme for your site to avoid having to create multiple themes.

You should also look at implementing a mobile menu, I recommend https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_menu although there is a small cost for commercial use of one of the scripts